# javascript sort distances with different units

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting, google-maps-api-3

How can you sort an array of distances when the units are being returned in both miles and feet?

For example, I'll get 327 feet, 1.5 miles. 20 miles. etc. The problem is that when trying to sort by distance, feet will often be last because its numerical value is higher. Is it possible to always calculate something with feet first in an array?

here's the code:

```
_locationset.sort(function (a, b) {
       return ((a.Distance < b.Distance) ? -1 : ((a.Distance >b.Distance) ? 1 : 0));
});
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: How are the units indicated within the array?

Comment: presumably you no longer care about solving this question.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not possible, you have to convert your feet into miles first.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing from the tag you are using the Google Maps API. How are you getting your distance from the google maps API?

Distances from the google maps API are available in a string representation using a specified unit system, but they are also available in a number representation always in meters. Could you use the number representation and sort on that?

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Distance

Comment: If this is the case, said implementation should work just fine.

Fun fact: a shorter way to write the return value would be `(a.Distance > b.Distance) - (a.Distance < b.Distance)`. Of course, this is generally a bad idea, since type coercion is very messy :)